# Get only unique entries from a list

Tags: excel, powershell, vba

I've got a list of email addresses and a lot of them have the same domain.

So say that we have a list like this:

- User1@domain.com
- User2@domain.com
- User3@domain.com
- User1@domain2.com
- User2@domain2.com

What I want is do remove the items I don't need:

- User2@domain.com
- User3@domain.com
- User2@domain2.com

Leaving only:

- User1@domain.com
- User1@domain2.com

I've manage to make a PS script where you can delete the row in a CSV-file which contains an email address that we don't need, but the problem is that this script is deleting every address containing the string:

```
Get-Content 'C:\list.csv' | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'domain'}| Set-Content C:\out.csv
```

So if I use this script, it will delete every row containing "domain" but I want to save the first row that contains it.

Comment: Does your file contain anything else, or just the list of mail addresses (one per line)?

Comment: Can you confirm that you're trying to get just the unique domain names from the list of email addresses?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that I'm trying to get just the unique domain names from the list.
The list it self onöy contains addresses and nothing else.

Comment: Are you looking for an Excel VBA anser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
#Seems this is a txtfile and not csv, so we'll just read it as text
Get-Content 'C:\list.csv' |
#Group by domain
Group-Object { $_ -replace '^.*@' } |
#Get first address per domain
ForEach-Object { $_.Group[0] } |
#Save to file
Set-Content C:\out.csv
```

Output:

```
User1@domain.com
User1@domain2.com
```

If you only need the domain-names, you can use:

```
#Read file
Get-Content 'C:\list.csv' |
#Group by domain
Group-Object { $_ -replace '^.*@' } |
#List group names (domain names)
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
#Save to file
Set-Content C:\out.csv
```

Output:

```
domain.com
domain2.com
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one match for each unique email address you could use select-object -unique:

```
Get-Content 'C:\list.csv' | Select-Object -Unique | Set-Content C:\out.csv
```

It sounds though that you want a unique entry for each email domain. Does it matter which entry it is? The following PowerShell code would get the first match for each domain (it assumes you CSV file has a header of "emailaddress" for the email address field:

```
Import-CSV 'list.csv' | ForEach-Object { 
    $_ | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Domain -Value ($_.emailaddress -split '@')[1] 
    Write-Output $_
} | Group-Object Domain | ForEach-Object { $_ | Select -ExpandProperty Group | Select emailaddress -First 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Dictionary` to store only the unique domains.

The code below will loop through all email addresses in column A (starting from cell "A2" - you can modify to fit your needs), and then it uses the `Split` function to split the email address and the domain's name (into `EmailArr` array).

Afterwards, confirm that the `EmailArr(1)` that represents the domain name is unique by making sure it's not already in the `Dictionary`, you achieve this by the following code line : `If Not Dict.exists(EmailArr(1)) Then` --> and that's it, you have a `Dictionary that stored only unique domain names.

At the end, I added a loop to display the unique domain names in a `MsgBox` (you can put them in an Array or a Range).

**Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub KeepUniqueDomains()
    Dim Dict As Object
    Dim EmailArr As Variant
    Dim C As Range, LastRow As Long
    Dim Key As Variant

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Sheets("Sheet7") '<-- modify "Sheet7" with your sheet's name
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For Each C In .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Cells
            EmailArr = Split(C.Value, "@")

            If Not Dict.exists(EmailArr(1)) Then
                Dict.Add EmailArr(1), EmailArr(1)
            End If
        Next C
    End With

    Dim MsgStr As String
    For Each Key In Dict.keys
        MsgStr = MsgStr & Key & vbCr
    Next Key
    MsgBox "Unique domain names in the list are :" & vbCr & MsgStr
End Sub
```